# Solve $z^6+7z^3-8=0$

Tags: complex-numbers, roots, quadratics

I want to find the solutions $z^6+7z^3-8=0$ but I don't know where to start because of the high degree of the equation.

This is an exercise that involves complex numbers, so I have to transform the equation into trigonometric form and then use the de Moivre formula.

Any hints?

Comment: Start by writing $z^{3}=x$ maybe?

Comment: **Hint:** $$z^6+7z^3-8=(z^3+8)(z^3-1)$$ The solutions should be $z=1,w,w^2,-2,-2w,-2w^2$ where $w$ denotes a primitive cube root of unity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$(z^3 + 8)(z^3 - 1) {}{}{}{}$$

Answer (score 1):

Using Mathematica

```
poly = z^6 + 7 z^3 - 8;
```

Factor the polynomial and solve the equations formed by setting each factor equal to zero

```
factoredPoly = Factor[poly]

(*  (-1 + z)*(2 + z)*(4 - 2*z + z^2)*(1 + z + z^2)  *)
```

This reduces the problem to solving quadratic and linear equations

```
soln = Flatten[Solve[# == 0, z] & /@ List @@ factoredPoly, 1]

(*  {{z -> 1}, {z -> -2}, {z -> 1 - I*Sqrt[3]}, 
   {z -> 1 + I*Sqrt[3]}, {z -> -(-1)^(1/3)}, 
   {z -> (-1)^(2/3)}}  *)
```

Verifying that this is equivalent to solving the original equation

```
(soln // Sort) == Solve[poly == 0, z]

(*  True  *)
```